# Custom Authorization (Restriction)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a custom authorization that takes `BranchId`, `StaffId` and `RoleId`. The Staff can only be allowed to view only his branch when logging in to the application because the `branchId` is part of the added staff url.

I managed to get the `id` from the url and passed to string, but I can't figure out how to use this id to check the `branch id` of the current user and then check to see if the staff should be on the branch and what role before allowing access.

Here is my example. I am new in `.net`. How can I do such method?

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                     RestrictViewRequirement requirement)
{
    int? branchId = null;     
    if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext authContext)
    {
        var tmp = authContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["branchId"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
        {
            branchId = int.Parse(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two options to have user data in it's request, First option if you are using normal ASP.NET(have `session` in your application, use session to store user data after user successfully logged in). Second, if you are using API, you can use `JWT` (Json Web Token) and pass it to front-end, so in every request you have the token to authorize and authenticate user based on it (you can have claim inside the token such as branchID or ect.)

Comment: I am using ASP.NET user is not to be allowed to log in successfully till all the requirement are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user's branch id as Claim and then check it against the branch id you are getting from the URL.

You can add the User's Branch id as Claim in the GenerateUserIdentityAsync function

```
// Add custom user claims here
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("BranchId", "XYZ"));
return userIdentity;
```

Now when you want to check it, You can get the branch id from the claim.
You can get the Claim back like this:

```
var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
var branchid = ci.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == "BranchId")?.Value;
```

Comment: was this answer or comment?

Comment: I already have users in my database I do not want to add custom user

Comment: We are not adding custom user to database. We are only adding claim to principal. This will neither change the database structure, nor the database data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging with Identity `SignInManager`, you can Dependency Injection the `UserManager` into the `CustomAuthorizationHandler`, and then you can get the current login User.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RestrictViewRequirement>
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public CustomAuthorizationHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RestrictViewRequirement requirement)
    {
        var currentUser = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        //....
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```